# Speed up dig -x in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, loops, dig

I have to run as an exercise at my university a bash script to reverse lookup all their DNS entries for a B class network block they own.

This is the fastest I have got but takes forever.  Any help optimising this code?

```
#!/bin/bash
network="a.b"

CMD=/usr/bin/dig

for i in $(seq 1 254); do

    for y in $(seq 1 254); do
        answer=`$CMD -x $network.$i.$y +short`; 
        echo $network.$i.$y ' resolves to ' $answer >> hosts_a_b.txt;
    done
done
```

Comment: Think of **GNU Parallel** when you want to do lots of stuff in parallel...

Comment: Doing more than 64000 DNS lookups is going to take a while no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU xargs to run 64 processes at a time might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

lookupArgs() {
  for arg; do
    # echo entire line together to ensure atomicity
    echo "$arg resolves to $(dig -x "$arg" +short)"
   done
}
export -f lookupArgs

network="a.b"
for (( x=1; x<=254; x++ )); do
  for (( y=1; y<=254; y++ )); do
    printf '%s.%s.%s\0' "$network" "$x" "$y"
  done
done | xargs -0 -P64 bash -c 'lookupArgs "$@"' _ >hosts_a_b.txt
```

Note that this doesn't guarantee order of output (and relies on the `lookupArgs` function doing one `write()` syscall per result) -- but output is sortable so you should be able to reorder. Otherwise, one could get ordered output (and ensure atomicity of results) by switching to GNU parallel -- a large perl script, vs GNU xargs' small, simple, relatively low-feature implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is significantly faster. The same scan took more than an hour with my code but only 26 mins with your modification

Comment: It is a pretty dangerous solution: In this case it will work (reverse names are typically much shorter than 1000 bytes), but you are playing with fire. Longer lines (>1008 bytes) or multiple writes would open you to raceconditions with half-line mixing. Not stressing the limitations makes it seem as if you are unaware of them: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Non-atomic_writes_with_xargs_-P

Comment: You've seen me stress those limitations in other situations where they *can* be reasonably expected to be hit -- this isn't our first discussion on the topic. That said, a bit more emphasis could be reasonably called for here, and I've edited appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

A fair chunk of the time is just starting the `dig` command for every single address.

Better would be to handle a reasonable number of addresses in one command, and then post-process that to produce the output you desire. (If you don't like the raw output, add the `sed` command I've given at the end of this answer.)

For a /16 network I suggest something like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    N=192.168.
    printf %s\\n -x"$N"{0..255}.{0..255} |
    xargs -r -n64 -P64 dig +noall +ans +nocl +nottl
```

The `-n64` means that each invocation of `dig` will output around 3800 bytes depending on how long the resulting names are. As long as the entire output of each `dig` is less than 4096 bytes, it will be written as a single `write()` syscall.

If you have long domain names causing interleaving, the simplest fix is to reduce the `-n` option, but that will make it somewhat slower.

Another way to mitigated this is to have each invocation of `dig` write to a separate output file, and then combine them at the end. For example:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    d="/tmp/tmpdir$$"
    mkdir "$d"
    N=192.168.
    p=0 w=64
    for (( c=0 ; c < 256 ; ++c )) do
        (( ++p <= w )) || wait -n
        dig +noall +ans +nocl +nottl "$N$c".{0..255} > "$d/$c" &
    done
    wait
    cat "$d"/*
```

Lastly, if you have administrative access to the authoritative nameserver, then you could configure the nameserver to allow zone transfers to a host of your choosing. Then you could get everything in a few *seconds* using a single command:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    dig @ns.your.domain. +noall +ans +nocl +nottl axfr 168.192.in-addr.arpa
```

The commands I've given above all output the raw `dig` format; you can convert this to the requested format using a filter like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    (command as above ...) |
    sed 's/^\([0-9.]*\)\..*[[:space:]]/\1\t/
         s/\.$//
         s/^\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\t/\4.\3.\2.\1\t/
         s/\t/  resolves to  /'
```